# iOS7 dirty rect drawing weirdness

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-graphics

I have been developing a cad-like drawing app for iOS, which makes careful use of dirty rect clipping to make for a smooth drawing experience - it has worked quite well for months. Now, I know iOS doesn't automatically clip dirty rects, but CoreGraphics will. For reference, here's what the preamble of my main view's drawRect function looks like (leaving out the actual drawing mechanism)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    if ( !CGRectIsNull(dirtyRect))
    {
        CGContextClipToRect( context, dirtyRect );
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM( context, self.viewTransform );

    .... drawing here, all done by CG* vector and bitmap functionsa

    CGContextRestoreGState( context );
}
```

Now, this code worked beautifully for a long time, iOS6, early iOS7 builds, etc. Smooth as butter. But just recently, I've been seeing a VERY odd set of behaviors, and I'm curious if anybody here has had similar experiences.

First, I trigger redraws the normal way, setNeedsDisplay when I need to redraw the whole view, and setNeedsDisplayInRect passing a dirty rect for just the small bit that needs redrawing. Weirdly, recently when I call setNeedsDisplayInRect the rect I pass is *ignored*, and instead drawRect receives a rect matching the view's *bounds* and not the intended subrect. I only noticed this when testers reported dramatically bad drawing performance compared to previous builds - I've been using the simulator too much recently and hadn't noticed :/

I suspected this might be the result of some kind of multiple-dirty-rect union, so I overloaded setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsDisplayInRect, tracing when they got called, but that let nowhere. So then I decided to track my dirty rect manually as an iVar in the my rendering view class. Here's where the second oddity shows up: when I clip to the now *correct* dirty rect, the contents outside the dirty rect are cleared.

They should NOT be cleared. I have explicitly set self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO, so I don't understand why the behavior I'm seeing is happening, particularly when it wasn't happening in the past.

Now, I'm probably going to do a git-bisect style of debugging to see if I can find a version way back when which didn't have this bug. But I'm hoping somebody here with CoreGraphics experience can lend me some conceptual support. This has me totally baffled.

P.S. I haven't touched the drawing code for my app in a long time since I've spent the last few months developing the app *around* the drawing tools. This is why I suspect a change to iOS7's drawing pipeline may play some kind of role here.

Comment: Turns out it was my bug - which is good, because now it's fixed! And I don't need to wait for Apple to fix something which would be very hard to build a reproducible demo for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include this line in your code inside drawRect method :-

```
 [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
```

Comment: Please explain how that would affect the size of the dirty rect.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who stumbles across this in the future when searching for help with iOS dirty rects, I want to say I solved this, and it was *my* bug, not apple's. I spent a morning doing a git bisect to narrow down when the trouble showed up, and found that when I did some refactoring back in early october, I introduced some change notifications to my model which were indirectly causing a setNeedsDisplay which overwrote the setNeedsDisplayInRect my touch handling code was laboriously computing.

So - not an apple bug!

Answer (score 0):

drawRect:dirtyRect is for mac. For ios you should use drawRect:rect. It should be called with setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: Incorrect. If you pass a dirty rect to setNeedsDisplayInRect you can manually clip your CGContext rendering to that rect. It works beautifully, when you do it correctly.